# Interesting problem on determinant (and pinch of number theory)

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

> The digits A, B and C are such that the three digit numbers A88 , 6B8
> and 86C are divisible by 72, what is $$\begin{vmatrix}
>     A & 6 & 8\\
>      8 & B & 6 \\ 8 & 8 & C \end{vmatrix} \pmod {72}$$

I can (and did) find the individual digits B and C , A was a bit harder to find. And then solved the expanded the Determinant. This was quite time consuming.

Is it possible to solve this solely using properties of determinant (or matrix)?
Edit: without actually finding the digits

Comment: If $A88$ is divisible by $9$, $A$ must be $2$ to make the sum of digits $18$.

Comment: @Ross -- the question makes it clear that they know how to find the digits that way. They're asking if there's a shortcut using the properties of determinants.

Comment: @dbx he just says that because OP says that $A$ was hard to find

Comment: @Ross Millikan, I edited the question. And thanks, didn't think of that

Comment: @dbx "*that way*"  No, it isn't clear that they knew how to find the digits in an efficient way at all... "*A was a bit harder to find*" implying that they didn't know about "casting out nines"

Comment: Why don't you show the concrete matrix (since you found out $A,B,C$) ?

Comment: @Peter, there  will be no point in asking the question then.

Comment: Now... consider taking the third row and adding ten times the second row plus a hundred times the first row.  What do you get?  What should doing this have done to the determinant?

Comment: @JMoravitz, yes, I didn't think of that, I was just using 72 as a whole.

Comment: @user675453 This is this kind of context people expect here ! And it improves your question significant, if you show your work.

Comment: @dbx, Yes, I found the digit, in this case I was lucky that i found it in second trial(as it's 2).

Comment: @JMoravitz, I don't understand your comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since replacing a row in a matrix by that same row plus a multiple of another row *does not change the determinant*, we see that by replacing the third row by the third row plus ten times the second row plus a hundred times the first row... that is... by performing the modification:

$$R_3 \leftarrow R_3 + 10R_2+100R_1$$

we arrive at a matrix who should have the same determinant as before.  The new third row however has every entry divisible by $72$, as per our hypothesis, noting that the entries in our new third row are precisely those three-digit numbers $A88, 6B8$ and $86C$

As such, it follows that the determinant itself is divisible by $72$ and is then equivalent to $0$ when considered modulo $72$.

Answer (score 0):

Once we have $A,B,C$ we are after
$$\begin{vmatrix}
    2 & 6 & 8\\
     8 & 4 & 6 \\ 8 & 8 & 4 \end{vmatrix} \pmod {72}$$
We note we can divide each row by $2$, which shows the determinant is a multiple of $8$.  If we do the division we can work $\bmod 9$, so we now want
$$\begin{vmatrix}
    1 & 3 & 4\\
     4 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 4 & 2 \end{vmatrix} \pmod {9}$$
Now we can add the first row to the third and the second row to the third, getting a row of $0$s. The original determinant is then $0 \pmod {72}$

Comment: I didn't want to do this way...

Comment: You asked for something easier than expanding, which this is.

Comment: later I edited and added another line.. (which I now realise isn't quite visible)

Comment: As I noted in a comment, finding the digits is easy by casting out $9$s